# Name of polyomino using shapes other than a square

Tags: terminology, polyomino

Is there a name to describe polyominoes that use shapes other than a square? Wolfram alpha could not answer this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Polyiamonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyiamond) are shapes composed of equilateral triangles similar to polyominoes and squares. I have seen [polyhex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhex_(mathematics)) for those made of regular hexagons

Comment: And on the [polyform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyform) wiki page is a list of names for polyforms using other shapes.